# Using predict to find values of non-linear model

Tags: r, lm

I'm trying the next code to try to see if predict can help me to find the values of the dependent variable for a polynomial of order 2, in this case it is obvious y=x^2:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5 , 6)
y <- c(1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36)
mypol <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 2, raw=TRUE))

> mypol

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE))

Coefficients:
            (Intercept)  poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE)1  poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE)2  
                      0                        0                        1
```

If I try to find the value of x=7, I get this:

```
> predict(mypol, 7)
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : not that many frames on the stack
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you read the help for `predict.lm`, you will see that it takes a number of arguments including `newdata`

> *newdata* --   An optional data frame in which to look for variables with
>   which to predict. If omitted, the fitted values are used.

```
predict(mypol, newdata = data.frame(x=7))
```

Comment: Hi mnel, how can I do the same for multiple values. Say, in this example, 7,8,9,10 etc etc? How can I get the predictions for all values?

Comment: @CodingInCircles create the appropriate data.frame `newdata = data.frame(x = c(7,8,9,10)))` or ``newdata =data.frame(x = seq(7, 10, by = 15))` or whatever you want.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! :) Also.. can you tell me how we represent y=e^x in the notation like `y ~ e^x`?

Comment: @CodingInCircles -- you won't be able to use `lm` for that, either fit `glm(y~x, family = gaussian(link = log))` or `nls(y~a*exp(b*x),start = list(a=1,b=1))`

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot! :) Didn't mean to hijack this question though.. :P